# Relationship between Wasserstein projections and metric projections in a linear space

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control, approximation-theory, combinatorial-optimization, optimal-transportation

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $x\in X$, and $Y\subset X$ is a closed set. Assume that $X$ is also a real vector space, so that we can form linear combinations over $\mathbb{R}$, but *I do not assume that the metric $d$ respects the linear structure in any way*.

I can always write $x$ as a convex combination $x=\sum_{n=1}^N w_nx_n$ ($w_n\ge 0$, $\sum w_n=1$, $x_n\in X$). Fix such a representation (of course this is not unique). Now consider the following two problems, where $M\ge N$:
$$
\inf_{y\in Y} d(x,y) \quad(*) \\
\inf \left\{W_1\left(\sum_{n=1}^N w_n\delta_{x_n}, \sum_{m=1}^M w_m\delta_{y_m}\right) : \sum_{m=1}^M w_my_m \in Y \right\} \quad(**)
$$

Here, $W_1$ is the 1-Wasserstein metric (the order is not super important).

*Can anything be said about these relation between these two problems?* For example, If $(*)$ has a solution $y$ and $(**)$ has a solution $\sum_{m=1}^M w_m\delta_{y_m}$, must $y = \sum_{m=1}^M w_my_m$? If not, are there conditions that ensure this? How far apart can these solutions be (as measured by $d$ in the obvious way)? Can one have a solution but the other does not?